# Oracle APEX: Tooltip on cell of the report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an APEX tabular form, all columns of which are standard report columns.
Is it possible to display a tooltip on mouse over of a particular cell of the report?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the report column attributes look for the region named Column Formatting. Inside this section is a text box for an "HTML Expression". Here you can add html to the report column contents e.g., `<span title="My tooltip text">#COLUMN_NAME#</span>`

The tooltip text could be from another column, you would just replace the contents of the title attribute with the column name surrounded by hashes.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION 1:**
If your record needs to be editable then this solution works:

Under column attributes go to LINK
For Target: Type - URL and URL is *just* a *hashtag*
*URL:* #

*Link Text:* &COLUMN_NAME.

*Link Attributes:* title="&COLUMN_NAME." class="column_name_class"

Then in your inline CSS add the following

```
.column_name_class{
    text-decoration: none !important; 
 }
```

Solution one I definitely prefer. But here is solution 2 anyways.

**SOLUTION 2:**

[See here for the solution on JSDoc: Widget Grid](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aexjs/grid.html#tooltip)

You can also initialize the grid with the tooltip option specified.

```html
function( options ) {
    options.defaultGridViewOptions = {
        tooltip: {
            content: function( callback, model, recordMeta, colMeta, columnDef ) {
                var text;
                // calculate the tooltip text
                return text;
            }
        }
    };
    return options;
}
} );
```

Calculating the tooltip :

```
config.defaultGridViewOptions = {
    tooltip: {
        content: function( callback, model, recordMeta, colMeta, columnDef ) {
            
            return model.getValue( recordMeta.record, "COLUMN_NAME");
          
        }
    }
}
```

```
function( options ) {
options.defaultGridViewOptions = {
    tooltip: {
        content: function( callback, model, recordMeta, colMeta, columnDef ) {
            var text;
            // calculate the tooltip text
            return model.getValue( recordMeta.record, "COLUMN_NAME");
           
        }
    }
};
return options;
```

}